# NGinX - [emerg] "ssl_certificate" directive is duplicate - Add new SSL Enabled site breaks NGinx Conf

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to add a second SSL enabled site to my NGinX configuration. Everything works fine with just one SSL enabled site, but when I add the second conf -- which is just an edited and copied conf from the working site -- I get the following error.

Note: I have tested and if I remove the new site, the conf passes and vice versa, if I remove the old site, the new one works.

```
root@NGinX:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ytitconf
 * Reloading nginx configuration nginx                                                           [fail]
nginx: [emerg] "ssl_certificate" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ytit.conf:2
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Here is the VERY simple configuration in its whole.

Note: The second site hosts multiple subdomains, but this site will not be hosting subdomains at the moment.

```
root@NGinX:/etc/nginx/sites-available# cat ytit.conf
#GLOBAL SSL
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle-ytit.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server-ytit.key;


server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.ytit.ca ytit.ca;

       return         301 https://$server_name/;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl on;
server_name www.ytit.ca ytit.ca;
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

location / {

      proxy_pass           https://192.168.1.169:443/;
      include             /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;

    }
}
```

Here is NGinX.conf; I don't think its modified, but I set up NGinX almost a year ago and don't remember to be honest, so I'm including it as the error says it's with NGinX.conf test.

```
root@NGinX:/etc/nginx/sites-available# cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # nginx-naxsi config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
        ##

        #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

        ##
        # nginx-passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
        ##

        #passenger_root /usr;
        #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

nothing extra in conf.d

```
root@NGinX:/etc/nginx/conf.d# ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 29  2015 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Mar  8  2016 ../
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main config file contains the line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` which drags in all config files within the named directory sequentially.

All directives not within named context default to the `global` context, therefore by defining `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificates` in the top level of these files you are redefining a global directive, which causes NginX to complain.

Your options are:

- Move the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificates` inside a `server` context, which allows you to configure different certificates for different sites;
- Only have the `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificates` directives in just one of these site conf files in a global context which makes it cover all your servers.  Alternatively, moving it to the top level `nginx.conf` file will have the same effect.

Note that from version 1.11 you can have multiple `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificates` directives to cover different certificate types (RSA,ECDSA etc).

Comment: I understand, so what I do now is my "oddball" sites get SSL inside the `server block` while my main site which is constantly having subdomains added/removed has the SSL in the `global block` so I don't have to add it to each subdomain.